# How can I visualize this recursive implementation of finding the maximum number of a list?

Tags: java, scala, recursion

I have a recursive function to find the largest number in a list. I wrote the function by following a tip I came across once. The tip suggest that when trying to find the maximum integer in a list of integers is to:

1. Cover base cases
2. Imagine if there is a another function that gives the max of the tail of the list.
3. replace the imaginary function with your function

So the pseudo-code will look like

```
def max(somelist: List[Int]): Int = {
  // base case 1: empty then error out
  if (somelist.isEmpty) {
   Error out
  }
  // base case 2: if the list has one elements 
  if (somelist.tail.isEmpty) {
    somelist.head
  }
  // Otherwise imagine I have a function that return the max of the tail of the list
  // call it imaginary_max(tailOfList).
  // get the max of the tail and then compare to the head of your list
  // and return the appropriate result.
  // replace imaginary_max with max and it works

  else {
    val m = max(somelist.tail);      
    if (somelist.head > m) {
      somelist.head
    }
    else {
      m
    }
  }
}
```

This works but I am having troubles visualizing what is happening in the background especially when I try to explain it to others. Any help and guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. I have dealt with it long time ago in cs school. I feel like my understanding of recursion is fair but not 100%.

Comment: The best way to visualize recursion is _interactively_.  You could use a debugger to step through the code and view the values of the various variables.  This would also allow you to see how each recursive call contains its own arguments and local variables, which differ from call to call, so that each function call is independent of the other function calls.  I haven't used scala, but I'm assuming you could use Eclipse or IntelliJ to step through this code.  That's what I'd recommend.

Comment: @Jake I'm sure that's gradually getting better, but not so long ago the interactive debugger in IDEs (I used Eclipse) was not mature. That's why I started with tracing values instead, which was not ideal but was a practical workaround for what you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualization of recursion is usually easiest if you think of a stack.

Let's say I'm trying to find the max of `[1, 2, 5, 0]`, using your algorithm.   You might visualize it like this:

```
max( [0] ) => 0
max( [5, 0] ) => 5
max( [2, 5, 0] )
max( [1, 2, 5, 0] )
```

The bottom of the stack is where you start, you pass your input to `max()`.  The result of that first call is a call of `max` on the tail of the list, which is `[2, 5, 0]`.   Ditto the next level, except the next level is the base case.  So at the top of the stack, you return the number 5.   The number 5 "falls out of the stack" as the answer.

Comment: What I am failing to see when does comparison between numbers take place. Does it take place when the values start popping off the stack?

Comment: No it happens within the max() function

Comment: @awm, it _sort of_ happens as values start popping off the stack.  The important thing to note is that yes, you are right, all the calls happen before any comparisons... as the function calls return, the return values get assigned to `m`, and that's when the comparisons happen... I hope I explained that well...

Answer (score 2):

It's helpful to use the idea of a stack frame when trying to understand how recursion works.  To summarize briefly, a stack frame is simply a chunk of memory dedicated to storing the values of the arguments passed into a function and also the local variables defined in that function.  Any time you call a function, the new stack frame for that function goes on top of the stack frame for the current function -- and so on and so forth as you continue calling functions.  When the current function ends, its stack frame is "popped off" the current "call stack", which means that the variables associated with the calling function are now "at the top of the stack" or available for use.

Here's an image that may help demonstrate:

[image]

In this case, it looks like the call stack is actually growing downward, but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 1):

That’s a great use case for that tool I’m implementing, so I quickly adapted your source code.
Some traces are not needed for the final visualization, but I added them just in case:

```
package com.example

import org.stellabs.scart.tracing._

object KillerApp extends App{

  def max(somelist: List[Int]): Int =           s"max([${somelist mkString ", "}])".e_++:
  {
    // base case 1: empty then error out
    if (somelist.isEmpty) {
     ???
    }
    // base case 2: if the list has one elements 
    if (somelist.tail.isEmpty) {
      somelist.head
    }
    // Otherwise imagine I have a function that return the max of the tail of the list
    // call it imaginary_max(tailOfList).
    // get the max of the tail and then compare to the head of your list
    // and return the appropriate result.
    // replace imaginary_max with max and it works

    else {                                      ;|++: $$ s"recursion >> max(${somelist.tail})"
      val m = max(somelist.tail)                ;|++: $$ s"recursion << m = $m"
      if (somelist.head > m) {
        somelist.head
      }
      else {
        m
      }
    }
  }

  // MAIN
  max( {args map {_.toInt}}.toList )            e_++: 'main

}
```

**USE:**
You need SBT 0.13, from the command line (that works with Windows but I’ll use POSIX commands here):

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp
cd ~/tmp
git clone https://github.com/stellabs/scart.git
cd scart
git checkout v0.02.001
cd sbt

cd scart
sbt publishLocal
cd ..

cd template/inline
mv build.sbt build.sbt.ori
sed -e 's/all-last/as-is/' build.sbt.ori > build.sbt

# EDIT ./killerapp/src/KillerApp.scala,
# REPLACE CONTENTS WITH THE SOURCE SHOWN ABOVE
# SAVE

sbt run
# ...
> max([])<scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing>
[error] (run-main) scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
# ...

sbt "run 1 2 5 0"
# ...
> > recursion >> max(List(2, 5, 0))
> > > recursion >> max(List(5, 0))
> > > > recursion >> max(List(0))
> > > > max([0])=0
> > > > recursion << m = 0
> > > max([5, 0])=5
> > > recursion << m = 5
> > max([2, 5, 0])=5
> > recursion << m = 5
> max([1, 2, 5, 0])=5
> main=5
# ...
```

**EDIT**

That tool is a work in progress and has limitations.
Actually it's rather for debugging than for nice visualization.
That being said, here is a trick about indentations:

- `expression e_++: trace_data` is flat; best to trace vals/vars
- `trace_data.e_++:{ expression }` adds a level of indentation for *expression*; best to trace calls

For instance you might prefer:

```
  // MAIN
                                                'main.e_++:
  {
    max( {args map {_.toInt}}.toList )            
  }
```

Cheers.

Comment: +1 for adding indentation, function calls, function return values, and the comparison operations to the results.  Also for showing how to run the example, complete with the git clone...